# Spring-boot-maven-plugin run mainCLass in test package

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, mainclass

I need to run a SpringBootApplication which is in test package during my integration test with spring-boot-maven-plugin (start and stop goals)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <mainClass>launchers.ApplicationTestMode</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but I get with no surprise a `ClassNotFoundException`

How to run this SpringBootApplication in test package ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this running with:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <directories>
            <directory>target/test-classes</directory>
            <directory>target/classes</directory>
        </directories>
        <mainClass>launchers.ApplicationTestMode</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You have to add the `test-classes`.
I assume you are using the SpringBootApplication from your main code. So add the original `classes` as well.
If you use some test dependencies(e.g. testcontainers) in you `launchers.ApplicationTestMode`, then add `<useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>`